# File -> Create projector" is greyed out in Adobe Windows Flash Player Projector 14

Tags: windows-7, flash-player, swf

I want to convert a SWF to EXE with [Adobe Windows Flash Player Projector](https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html). To create the .exe from SWF I am supposed to go to "File -> Create projector" but the option is disabled:

[image]

Why?

Note that the option is enabled in some [older versions of Adobe Flash Player](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html) (e.g. [flashplayer10_2r152_32_win_sa.exe](http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/installers/archive/fp_10.2.152.32_archive.zip) works for me).

[image]

I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, infuriatingly enough, this 'bug' still persisting in the v14 of the player itself, it had been put in the adobe's bugbase since the v11 of the player

as it seems Adobe isn't giving any care about it, and is telling the DEV's that their best shot is to make it on Adobe's Air so it will end as a self-contained application, which as it seems could be ported to any kind of device

you, as like me, want to create the exe to use in windows in the desktop or laptop, but, hey, we're need to create it on Adobe's Air so we can use it in the cellphone or tablet or whatever, because Adobe says it...

[Adobe bugbase list](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3363321)

as you can check on the bugbase comments, there's a lot of people very disappointed for this change 'imposed' by Adobe